# Shell script for replacing string in all PHP-files, for each user

Tags: bash

Each user has some php-files using a shared database `commondb`. I want to iterate over all users (in users.csv), and in their home folder (e.g. /home/joe) find all php files recursively, and replace each occurrence of "commondb" with their own databasename, e.g. "joedb" for "joe".

I have tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Execute like this:
# bash localize.bash users.csv

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
while read name dummy
  do
    echo $name
    find /home/${name} -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '' 's/commondb/${name}db/g' "{}" \;

  done < $1
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

for users.csv

```
joe, Joe J
george, George G
```

It does not fail, but the files are unchanged. I am quite weak in bash, and I can't figure out how to debug it :/

Can my script be fixed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see anything wrong with your code at first. In fact I ran it and it worked fine, except that it replaced commondb with ${name} instead due to the use of single quotes in the sed command. Changing to double quotes worked fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Execute like this:
# bash localize.bash users.csv

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","
while read name dummy
  do
    echo $name
    find /home/${name} -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '' "s/commondb/${name}db/g" "{}" \;

  done < $1
IFS=$OLDIFS
```